# Using bootstraptoggle's onclick event in a scala-js application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scala, scala.js, scalatags

In my scala-js application I want to use the [bootstraptoggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com) library to create a nice looking switch button.

So far I am creating the toggle button by a method looking somewhat like this:

```
import scalatags.JsDom
import scalatags.JsDom.all._
// ...


def createToggleButton(): JsDom.TypedTag[Input] = {
  def onClick = println("HELLO WORLD!")
  input(id := "myToggle",
        attr("data-toggle") := "toggle",
        `type` := "checkbox",
        onclick := onClick,
        attr("data-on") := "ON",
        attr("data-off") := "OFF",
        attr("data-onstyle") := "success",
        attr("data-width") := "85",
        attr("data-height") := "26")
}
```

When rendering this and adding it to my DOM it looks like this:

[image: toggle off]
[image: toggle on]

So far everything is working. The peculiar thing is this however: 
When rendering the page ('F5') my console (Chrome - 'F12') shows one 'HELLO WORLD!' output right from the start. After that, **the onclick event does not seem to fire** anymore.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wasn't able to get the bootstrap-toggle to work, I decided to make my own. So, here is my solution: [ToggleSwitchWithLabels.scala](https://gist.github.com/fbaierl/5cb1616402ccb589b0d82691ec90b848)

Answer (score 2):

You should give a *function* of the form `() => action()` to the attribute `onclick`. Currently you're evaluating the `def onClick` once, and storing the result of that function call (which is the `()` value) in the `onclick` attribute. Instead you should write

```
onclick := { () => onClick }
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, that does not seem to work. I tried writing `onclick := { () => println("HELLO WORLD!") }` but now I don't get any output.

I noticed that it works with `onchange := { () => println("HELLO WORLD!") }` but then I will need a small work-around to distinguish if the user pressed the button or if it was changed by the API, so I would definetly prefer to use `onclick`.